# jquery input type file *.xlsx

Tags: jquery, file, input, types

does anybody knows why

```js
$('#id_thefile').attr('accept', '*.xlsx');
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- the input I want to change with jquery //-->
<input id="id_thefile" type="file" />
```

don't work?

Cheers,

Carlos.

Comment: No need of `*` simply use `'.xlsx'`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('#id_thefile').attr('accept', '*.xlsx');
```

to

```
$('#id_thefile').attr('accept', '.xlsx');
```

or

you can also directly add that in HTML accept like below

```html
<html>
<head>
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- the input I want to change with jquery //-->
<input id="id_thefile" type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx"/>
```